# Alamofire issue getting data from web service

Tags: ios, swift2, alamofire

Hello

I'm trying to use Alamofire library to access to a Rest API, The problem that I'm having is the following:

I have the following method:

```
func LoadDevices() ->Void{
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(priority, 0)) {
        // do some task
        do{
            try self.devices = self.manager.GetDevices(self.identity?.IdentityUser, password: self.identity?.IdentityPassword)!
            let lastDeviceConnected = self.manager.RetrieveSharedLastDeviceConnected()
            if(self.devices.count > 0 && lastDeviceConnected == nil){
                self.manager.SaveSharedLastDeviceConnected(self.devices[0].DeviceNumber!)
                self.manager.SaveSharedLastDeviceConnectedObject(self.devices[0])
                self.deviceData = try self.manager.GetDeviceData(self.identity?.IdentityUser!, password: self.identity?.IdentityPassword!, deviceNumber: self.devices[0].DeviceNumber!)
                if(self.deviceData != nil){
                    self.manager.SaveSharedDeviceDataJson(DeviceData.DeviceDataToJson(self.deviceData!))

                }
            }
        }catch{
            self.devices = [Device]()
        }
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }
}
```

In this method I'm calling a method "GetDevices", this method have the following code:

```
func GetDevices(user: String?, password: String?) ->[Device]?{
    let myIdentity = RetrieveSharedIdentityObject()
    let url = "https://" + (myIdentity?.ServerAccount)! + "/account/account/account/" + (myIdentity?.IdentityAccountNumber)! + "/devices"
    var devices : [Device]?
    let headers = [
        "MMSSession": myIdentity!.ServerAccountToken!,
    ]
    Alamofire.request(.GET, url, headers: headers)
        .responseJSON { response in
            print(response.data)
            let json = JSON(data: response.data!)
            print(json)
            let device = Device()
            devices?.append(device)

    }
    return devices
}
```

As you can see I'm trying to access to an API using Alamofire, but when I executed this I don't get the data printed and also I'm getting an exception because i'm getting a nil value in the first method.

Please any help with this probably someone have any idea of why the Alamofire code doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The callback which received the data is called asynchronously. So you need to update the date in the callback, not after the call (which will return immediately, before having received the data).

Comment: Thank you very much @jcaron, I'm new with this, could explain me a bit more, I understand that you are suggesting me that I should return the "devices" into the .responseJSON{}

Comment: No, you should not return it, you should either use it at that point, or pass it along to a callback block provided by your function.

Comment: Thanks again, but I think if I can't return the list of devices i have to change my whole application, because I have the application using: `NSData(contentsOfURL: NSURL(string: urlToRequest)!)` but I'm trying with Alamofire because I have to call the methods using a Header in the request.